# Local URL IP redirect via port

Tags: macos, redirect, dns, hosts

I do a lot of custom web development and I am looking for a solution to a problem with testing.

I have a local development server that I run sandboxed environments on. When I need to test something I sometimes will edit my host file to make the domain point at my local IP

In my host file I would have.

```
127.0.0.1     mydomainname.com
```

What I would rather be able to setup is if I added a port to a URL:

```
mydomainname.com:7777
```

That would then redirect to my local IP

Something like this

```
127.0.0.1 *:7777
```

Is this a pipe dream or doable in someway?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/server-switcher/) [Server Switcher](http://hermann.czedik.net/projekte/switcher/)

This firefox extension is a tool for web developers and allows switching between sites on your development and live servers; it helps you to see difference immediately.

It's more easy in use than host file.